# How do I Set PHP Variables from URL Encoded Parameters?

Tags: php

Ok guys I got a situation here and I could use some help.

I get the parameters sent to me url encoded and they look like this

```
http://example.com/tyntec.php?sender%3D%2B16155305760%26receiver%3D%2B17874539876%26text%3Dplease+stop+sending+messages
```

I am trying to set my variables like this but that is not working because I guess the $_REQUEST is skipping the encoded & sign

```
$to = $_REQUEST['receiver'];
$from = $_REQUEST['sender'];
$text = $_REQUEST['text'];
```

How do I properly grab the parameters from the URL and set the variables?

Thanks in advance for helping me out.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried

Comment: As I am sure you guys can tell I am very new to coding php, Here i what I tried.

$to = urldecode($to);
$from = urldecode($from);
$text = urldecode($text);

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this:

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://example.com/tyntec.php?sender%3D%2B16155305760%26receiver%3D%2B17874539876%26text%3Dplease+stop+sending+messages
    ';
    $url = utf8_decode(urldecode($url));
    $parts = parse_url($url);
    parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
    echo $query['sender'];
    echo $query["receiver"];
    echo $query["text"];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
parse_str(  urldecode(  'http://example.com/tyntec.php?sender%3D%2B16155305760%26receiver%3D%2B17874539876%26text%3Dplease+stop+sending+messages' ), $output  );
var_dump($output);
```